# Is it possible to use an if-else construct in a pattern match in Scala?

Tags: scala, if-statement, pattern-matching

So this is a small Scala function which checks if a given List contains a given Char :

```
def contains: (List[Char], Char) => Boolean = {
    case (Nil, c) => false
    case (cs, c) if cs.head == c => true
    case (cs, c) if cs.head != c => contains(cs.tail, c)
  }
```

Now I was wondering if or rather how I could simplify the cases and have it be something like:

```
def contains: (List[Char], Char) => Boolean = {
    case (Nil, c) => false
    case (cs, c) if cs.head == c => true
                 else => contains(cs.tail,c)
  }
```

Comment: If you already have a guard (i.e. the `if` in the `case ... if ... =>`) you don't need the other one below as `case`s are checked sequentially from top to bottom. If you'd rather keep the `if/else` you could move it after the `case`, i.e. `case ... => if ... else ...`.

Comment: btw, your method can simplify to one line `def contains(cs: List[Char], c: Char): Boolean = cs.nonEmpty && (cs.head == c || contains(cs.tail, c))`

Comment: Stylistic nitpick: are you sure you want to have a method returning a function value? Perhaps a simple method would do, like `def contains(cs: List[Char], c: Char): Boolean = ...`?

Comment: Also, don't use `.head`, it's "code smell". `case (head::tail, c) => head == c or contains(tail, c)`

Answer (score 3):

The third case clause will be hit only if none of the first two matches, so you function effectively matches:

```scala
def contains: (List[Char], Char) => Boolean = {
    case (Nil, _) => false
    case (cs, c) if cs.head == c => true
    case (cs, c) => contains(cs.tail, c)
}
```

Note that in this particular case you can merge the last two cases by just using boolean logic:

```
def contains: (List[Char], Char) => Boolean = {
    case (Nil, _) => false
    case (cs, c) => cs.head == c || contains(cs.tail, c)
}
```